# Want to insert a new field to CSV with filename as attribute

Tags: csv, table, batch, timestamp

I have thousands of CSV files with the approximately the following structure:

csv_20160601T004301Z:

name,x,y,
name1,23,66
name2,23,67

csv_20160601T005001Z:

name,x,y,
name1,23,66
name2,23,67

etc.

As you can see, the filename contains a timestamp. I'd like to add a new field to each of the csv files and populate the field with the filename, like so:

csv_20160601T004301Z:

name,x,y,timestamp
name1,23,66,csv_20160601T004301Z
name2,23,67,csv_20160601T004301Z

csv_20160601T005001Z:

name,x,y,timestamp,
name1,23,66,csv_20160601T005001Z
name2,23,67,csv_20160601T005001Z

etc.

Of course, the "csv_" prefix is not really needed, just wanted to illustrate the idea. Any thoughts on how to do this? Is this something that can be achieved with Notepad++ or similar? Or will this require a more sophisticated approach?

---

I have very, very little experience in coding/programming, so I may need the potential ideas explained in the simplest way possible.

edit: SOLVED. I found a solution that helped me. I used the following in cmd:
for /f %a in ('dir /b *.csv') do for /f "tokens=*" %b in (%a) do echo %b,%a >> all.csv

Source: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/322603-merge-csv-files-and-create-a-column-with-the-filename-from-the-original-file

Comment: There does not seem to be a GIS component to this question.

Comment: You could use any of a dozen languages to accomplish this task. Try one.

Comment: I added this question under GIS because it felt like the safest place to go, since I work with geographic information here. I don't mind the idea of moving this question under another, more general IT topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple BASH script:

```
for i in csv_*      
do
  x=${i#csv_}
  awk '{print $0, '$x'}' $i
done
```